# CSS_responsive_html responsive

Tags: html, css

I have created a small game called 2048 by using html css and js
When I tried on the computer screen and test the responsive using dev tools, every thing was perfect.
However when I deploy by github this is the link
https://2048byrkph.netlify.app/
this is link to my github code
https://github.com/RKPH/2048

this is what I get from the pc sreen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0XAc.png)
and this is what is shown on my phone
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPLwr.png)

this is media screen using for responsvie

```
@media  screen and (min-width: 375px ) and (max-width:667px) {
    body {
        font-size: 16px; /* Adjust font size for better readability */
       
    }
    
    hr {
        width: 80%; /* Adjust hr width to fit the smaller screen */
        margin: 10px 0; /* Adjust hr margin for better spacing */
    }
    
    #board {
        margin-top: 10px; /* Adjust board margin for better spacing */
        width: 209.6px; /* Adjust board width to fit the smaller screen */
        height: 209.6px; /* Let the board height adjust dynamically */
    }
    
    .title {
        height: 50px; /* Adjust tile height for better fit */
        width: 50px; /* Adjust tile width for better fit */
        font-size: 24px; /* Adjust font size for better fit */
        border-width: 3px; /* Adjust border width for better fit */
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .modal-container {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        font-size: 10px;
        background-color: #cdc1b5;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
}



@media  screen and (min-width: 360px ) and (max-width:740px) {
    body {
        font-size: 16px; /* Adjust font size for better readability */
       
    }
    
    hr {
        width: 80%; /* Adjust hr width to fit the smaller screen */
        margin: 10px 0; /* Adjust hr margin for better spacing */
    }
    
    #board {
        margin-top: 10px; /* Adjust board margin for better spacing */
        width: 209.6px; /* Adjust board width to fit the smaller screen */
        height: 209.6px; /* Let the board height adjust dynamically */
    }
    
    .title {
        height: 50px; /* Adjust tile height for better fit */
        width: 50px; /* Adjust tile width for better fit */
        font-size: 24px; /* Adjust font size for better fit */
        border-width: 3px; /* Adjust border width for better fit */
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (device-width: 414) and (device-height: 812px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  {
    /* Adjust styles for iPhone 11 */
    body {
        font-size: 16px; /* Adjust font size for better readability */
       
    }
    
    hr {
        width: 80%; /* Adjust hr width to fit the smaller screen */
        margin: 10px 0; /* Adjust hr margin for better spacing */
    }
    
    #board {
     
        margin-top: 10px; /* Adjust board margin for better spacing */
        width: 309.6px; /* Adjust board width to fit the smaller screen */
        height: 309.6px; /* Let the board height adjust dynamically */
    }
    
    .title {
        height: 50px; /* Adjust tile height for better fit */
        width: 50px; /* Adjust tile width for better fit */
        font-size: 24px; /* Adjust font size for better fit */
        border-width: 3px; /* Adjust border width for better fit */
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
```

It works well when I test by devtool :(
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ePaj.png)
can somebody help me pls ,thank you vert much

Comment: The issue seems to be in your `.js`. Please look at the Answer below

Answer (score 0):

A very Good effort by you. Please try this amended `.js`. The amends are very minor. All Credits to you only.

```js
var board;
var score = 0;
var rows = 4;
var columns = 4;

window.onload = function() {
  setgame();
};

function setgame() {
  board = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0]
  ];

  for (let r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
      let title = document.createElement("div");
      title.id = r.toString() + "-" + c.toString();
      let num = board[r][c];
      updateTitle(title, num);
      document.getElementById("board").append(title);
    }
  }
}

function Endgame() {
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] === 0) {
        return true;
      }
      if (i > 0 && board[i][j] === board[i - 1][j]) {
        return true;
      }
      if (j > 0 && board[i][j] === board[i][j - 1]) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function updateTitle(title, num) {
  title.innerText = "";
  title.classList.value = "";
  title.classList.add("title");
  if (num > 0) {
    title.innerText = num;
    if (num <= 4096) {
      title.classList.add("x" + num.toString());
    } else {
      title.classList.add("x8192");
    }
  }
}

function addRandomTile() {
  const emptyCells = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      if (board[i][j] === 0) {
        emptyCells.push({
          row: i,
          col: j
        });
      }
    }
  }

  if (emptyCells.length > 0) {
    const randomCell = emptyCells[Math.floor(Math.random() * emptyCells.length)];
    const newValue = Math.random() < 0.9 ? 2 : 4;
    board[randomCell.row][randomCell.col] = newValue;
    const title = document.getElementById(randomCell.row.toString() + "-" + randomCell.col.toString());
    updateTitle(title, newValue);
  }
}

let touchStartX, touchStartY;

document.addEventListener("touchstart", (e) => {
  touchStartX = e.touches[0].clientX;
  touchStartY = e.touches[0].clientY;
});

document.addEventListener("touchend", (e) => {
  const touchEndX = e.changedTouches[0].clientX;
  const touchEndY = e.changedTouches[0].clientY;
  const dx = touchEndX - touchStartX;
  const dy = touchEndY - touchStartY;

  if (Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy)) {
    if (dx > 0) {
      slideRight();
    } else {
      slideLeft();
    }
  } else {
    if (dy > 0) {
      slideDown();
    } else {
      slideUp();
    }
  }
  addRandomTile();
});

document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if (e.code == "ArrowLeft") {
    slideLeft();
  } else if (e.code === "ArrowRight") {
    slideRight();
  } else if (e.code === "ArrowUp") {
    slideUp();
  } else if (e.code === "ArrowDown") {
    slideDown();
  }
  addRandomTile();
  document.getElementById("score").innerText = score;
  if (Endgame() == false) {
    document.querySelector(".modal").classList.add("d-none");
  }
});

function filterZero(row) {
  return row.filter(num => num != 0);
}

function slice(row) {
  row = filterZero(row);
  for (let i = 0; i < row.length - 1; i++) {
    if (row[i] == row[i + 1]) {
      row[i] *= 2;
      row[i + 1] = 0;
      score += row[i];
    }
  }
  row = filterZero(row);
  while (row.length < columns) {
    row.push(0);
  }
  return row;
}

function slideLeft() {
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    let row = board[i];
    row = slice(row);
    board[i] = row;
    for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
      let title = document.getElementById(i.toString() + "-" + c.toString());
      let num = board[i][c];
      updateTitle(title, num);
    }
  }
}

function slideRight() {
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    let row = board[i];
    row = row.slice().reverse();
    row = slice(row);
    row.reverse();
    board[i] = row;
    for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
      let title = document.getElementById(i.toString() + "-" + c.toString());
      let num = board[i][c];
      updateTitle(title, num);
    }
  }
}

function slideUp() {
  for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
    let col = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      col.push(board[i][c]);
    }
    col = slice(col);
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      board[i][c] = col[i];
      let title = document.getElementById(i.toString() + "-" + c.toString());
      let num = board[i][c];
      updateTitle(title, num);
    }
  }
}

function slideDown() {
  for (let c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
    let col = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      col.push(board[i][c]);
    }
    col.reverse();
    col = slice(col);
    col.reverse();
    for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      board[i][c] = col[i];
      let title = document.getElementById(i.toString() + "-" + c.toString());
      let num = board[i][c];
      updateTitle(title, num);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

hr {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

#board {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 409.6px;
  height: 409.6px;
  background-color: #cdc1b5;
  border: solid 5px #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*the two line make sure tile input in the borad will in line in each
                      row instead of stack on the other!*/
}

.title {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 5px solid #bbade0;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.x2 {
  background-color: #eee4da;
  color: #727371;
}

.x4 {
  background-color: #ece0ca;
  color: #727371;
}

.x8 {
  background-color: #f4b17a;
  color: white;
}

.x16 {
  background-color: #f59575;
  color: white;
}

.x32 {
  background-color: #f57c5f;
  color: white;
}

.x64 {
  background-color: #f65d3b;
  color: white;
}

.x128 {
  background-color: #edce71;
  color: white;
}

.x256 {
  background-color: #edcc63;
  color: white;
}

.x512 {
  background-color: #edc651;
  color: white;
}

.x1024 {
  background-color: #eec744;
  color: white;
}

.x2048 {
  background-color: #ecc230;
  color: white;
}

.x4096 {
  background-color: #fe3d3d;
  color: white;
}

.x8192 {
  background-color: #ff2020;
  color: white;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: none;
}

.modal-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.d-none {
  display: flex !important;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 375px) and (max-width:667px) {
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
    /* Adjust font size for better readability */
  }
  hr {
    width: 80%;
    /* Adjust hr width to fit the smaller screen */
    margin: 10px 0;
    /* Adjust hr margin for better spacing */
  }
  #board {
    margin-top: 10px;
    /* Adjust board margin for better spacing */
    width: 209.6px;
    /* Adjust board width to fit the smaller screen */
    height: 209.6px;
    /* Let the board height adjust dynamically */
  }
  .title {
    height: 50px;
    /* Adjust tile height for better fit */
    width: 50px;
    /* Adjust tile width for better fit */
    font-size: 24px;
    /* Adjust font size for better fit */
    border-width: 3px;
    /* Adjust border width for better fit */
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .modal-container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    font-size: 10px;
    background-color: #cdc1b5;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width:740px) {
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
    /* Adjust font size for better readability */
  }
  hr {
    width: 80%;
    /* Adjust hr width to fit the smaller screen */
    margin: 10px 0;
    /* Adjust hr margin for better spacing */
  }
  #board {
    margin-top: 10px;
    /* Adjust board margin for better spacing */
    width: 209.6px;
    /* Adjust board width to fit the smaller screen */
    height: 209.6px;
    /* Let the board height adjust dynamically */
  }
  .title {
    height: 50px;
    /* Adjust tile height for better fit */
    width: 50px;
    /* Adjust tile width for better fit */
    font-size: 24px;
    /* Adjust font size for better fit */
    border-width: 3px;
    /* Adjust border width for better fit */
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>2048</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="2048.css">
  <script src="2048.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>2048</h1>
  <hr>
  <h2 id="score">Score: <span id="score">0</span></h2>
  <div id="board">

  </div>

  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-container">
      <h1>GAME OVER</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank u so much however I still got the same issue, every test case on-screen solution by dev tools worked perfectly but when I deployed by GitHub and accessed to the project on iPhone 11 I got the  issue above, (all the title bond out of the border)
p/s It kinda worked on samsung 8 I am so confused

Comment: In that case you will nned to include code for detecting the Device type and then adjust font size, tile width, or margins accordingly. Its only a rendering problem now.